# Tricky SQL IF on UPDATE

Tags: sql

I have this UPDATE SQL:

```
UPDATE  o
SET     HolidayPay = lob.AllowHolidayPay ,
        AppreciationPay = lob.AllowAppreciationPay
FROM    Orders AS o
        INNER JOIN LineofBusiness AS lob ON o.LineofBusinessID = lob.LineofBusinessID
WHERE   o.StatusID != 156 -- ALL ORDERS THAT ARE NOT CLOSED
        AND o.TempOrDirect = 'T'
GO
```

I need to make the WHERE clause do more than just use the statusID. What needs to happen is if the statusID = 156, then it needs to also check the value of stageID. So if the statusID = 156, but stageID = 6, that's OK. If statusID is still 156 but the stageID is any other value, then the != part is observed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I'm way overcomplicating this. Rather than try to use a weird combination of exclude this but only if X and/or Y is true, I'm just going to use positive states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(o.StatusID != 156 OR (o.StageID=6 and o.StatusID=156))
```

Comment: You missed out the " AND o.TempOrDirect = 'T'" part of the WHERE

Comment: I had this but looking at my question I think I wasn't clear enough. This will not update where statusID = 156, but it will only now update where stageid = 6 and statusID = 156. 

I need it to only be concerned with statusID 156 only if the stage id is 6. All other rows in the table need to be updated as well.

Answer (score 1):

So stageID = 6 or StatusID != 156?

```
WHERE (o.StatusID != 156 
        OR stageID = 6)
    AND o.TempOrDirect = 'T'
```